# iPhoto 11 duplicates files when importing from "Auto Import" subfolder

Tags: iphoto

I was looking for a way to make iPhoto import my pictures from the hard disk and remove the copies, or use 'move' instead of 'copy' in the first place.

I'm using iTunes "~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Automatically\ Add\ to\ iTunes" folder to do the same for a long time and it works great.

So I looked for a similar folder in iPhoto.

Found "~/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Auto Import"

Great. it even works when I put some pictures files in it.

But there is a problem once I put a *folder* of pictures. once I do that I get every picture twice inside iPhoto. once in an "unnamed event" and once in an event named after the folder.

Any ideas how to solve this?